# Batch flip direction of selected lines in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, batch

Is there a way to flip the direction of all selected lines at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Editing toolbox in ArcToolbox has a tool called [Flip Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/flip-line.htm), which will reverse the direction of every line (or selected lines if any are selected) in the chosen feature class or layer.

This can be used from the toolbox in ArcMap, or using the syntax outlined in the ArcGIS Help site link above:

> Syntax
>
> ```
> FlipLine_edit (in_features)
> ```
>
> in_features | The input line feature class or layer. | Feature Layer

In arcpy this would look something like this:

```
arcpy.FlipLine_edit("C:/data/project.gdb/streams")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Didn't realize the tool it would work on selections or definition queries. Thanks!

Comment: @Tigerwoulds almost every tool runs on selections or definition queries if run on the layer in ArcMap.  I would say every tool does, but I'm not 100% sure on that